# Polling data based on date filters

Tags: python, apache-kafka

I have the below code that reads data from Kafka queue.

```
bootstrap_servers = ['server.com']
topicName = 'topicname'
consumer = KafkaConsumer(topicName, group_id='topic', bootstrap_servers=bootstrap_servers, auto_offset_reset='earliest', consumer_timeout_ms=20000)

data_list = []
for message in consumer:
    print(message)
    data = json.loads(message.value)
    df = json_normalize(data)
    data_list.append(df)
```

I am however trying to see if I can restrict the data based on certain timestamp.

Answer (score 1):

You can filter each message on your own that doesn't match the criteria you want to process with a simple if statement

Or you can get all the offsets of a particular timestamp, then seek your consumer to those timestamps before polling (careful about handling application restarts and not reprocessing the same range)

https://kafka-python.readthedocs.io/en/master/apidoc/KafkaConsumer.html?highlight=seek#kafka.KafkaConsumer.offsets_for_times